# Prevent Apple Mail from suggesting contacts from my personal contacts

Tags: mail.app, contacts

I have macOS and contact from two different account: personal (using my Gmail account) and professional (using an Microsoft Exchange server).

I'm using Gmail webmail for personal mail and Apple mail for professional mail.

Unfortunately, Apple Mail sometime suggest contact from my personal account which is problematic.

I still want to use contact for managing all my contacts though. How can I force Apple Mail to use only my professional contacts on the Microsoft Exchange server ?

Comment: Let me be sure, it's MS Exchange you're talking about?

Comment: @Thinkr yes it is, I will edit my question to precise it.

Comment: Alright. I have already answered this question but I deleted it because I was proposing a solution for iCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have macOS and contact from two different account: personal (using my Gmail account) and professional (using an Exchange server)…Apple Mail will sometimes suggest contacts from my personal account which is problematic.

This is, unfortunately, one of the drawbacks of combining both personal and work accounts on a single client; the app is trying to anticipate what you want to do but is erring.  There are a couple of things you can try:

- try setting the default directory service to Exchange
- Use a mail client like Outlook that allows you to “isolate” accounts (sorry, don’t have a better word for it).  You can (in Outlook) select the account in the sidebar and operate only within that account context.
- use different apps for personal and work, keeping them completely separate from each other

Comment: How to set the default directory service in Exchange?

Comment: If you have an Exchange (or LDAP server,), you’ll have access see [this article](https://support.apple.com/guide/contacts/find-contacts-in-a-network-directory-service-adrbk1564/13.0/mac/13.0) @Thinkr

Comment: Your answer make sense: since MacOS doesn't allow proper separation, I move to Thunderbird to access my Microsoft Exchange email.